# Flutter align a single child in row

Tags: flutter, alignment, row

I have a Column that has array of rows and each row has some container inside. Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget row() {
  return Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        width: 50,
        height: 100,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        width: 50,
        height: 150,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 50,
        height: 80,
      ),
    ],
  );
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        row(),
        Divider(),
        row(),
        Divider(),
        row(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I want to align blue containers to the bottom, without touching other containers position. How can I do that?
This my expected result:

[image]

Comment: wrap last blue container with `Align`

Comment: @pskink It doesn't work. same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try out this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget row() {
  return Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            width: 50,
            height: 100,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            width: 50,
            height: 150,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 50,
        height: 80,
      ),
    ],
  );
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        row(),
        Divider(),
        row(),
        Divider(),
        row(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the main Row with CrossAxisAlignment `end` and wrap the Amber inside one more row and declare that with the CrossAxisAlignment `start`.

**How this works?**

Since your blue container will now inside the main row and which is now declared with the CrossAxisAlignment.end and hence it will go with the parent alignment.

```
Widget row() {
  return Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: 50,
          height: 100,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: 50,
          height: 150,
        )
      ]),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 50,
        height: 80,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```